# Node js code statments not running as per order

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, callback

I am Ruby developer but have to write a script code in Node.js on AWS Lambda. Everything works fine but the issue is that code statements are not executing in order and instead of waiting for request.post to complete , the callback function calls and returns.

First statements of `RDS.executeStatement(params).promise()` works fine but after that instead of running `request.post` and db statement in success case then callback calls.  I want callback method should run  request.post completes.

How can I fix that issue?

```
 const params = {
    secretArn: 'xxx',resourceArn: 'xxxx',
    sql: `SELECT * FROM pins WHERE Pin_Code = 'XXX' and status='ENABLED'`,
    database: 'pincodes'
  }

  let data = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
  
  if (data['records'].length !== 0){
    
    const params = {
      url: 'https://development-api.mobixpress.net/v2/products/domesticrecharge',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({dialCode: '+1',productPriceId: productPriceID,receiverPhoneNumber: phone})
    };
    
    request.post(params, function(err, res, body) {
        if(err){
          status = 0;
        } else{
          status = 1;

          const params = {
            secretArn: 'xxx',resourceArn: 'xxxx',
            sql: `UPDATE pins SET status = 'DISABLED' WHERE Pin_Code = 'XXX' and status='ENABLED'`,
            database: 'pincodes'
          }

          let update = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
    
        }
    });
    
    
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: '200',
      headers: {},
      body: status,
    });
  }
```

Comment: You could simply add an .then(). this will be executed as soon as the request is finished - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: You haven't told NodeJS to wait for `request.post` to finish. You would do that with the `await` keyword. Or you could move the `callback()` function call into the `request.post` response handler.

Comment: can you please give any example if possible ...@MarkB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Ruby so i don't now if there is an equivalent there, but it looks like you tripped over Nodes asynchronous nature

This is the source of the famous JS-callback hell. And especially if you are mixing promises with classic callbacks, this can become a confusing nightmare in no-time.

this article will tell you all about it and how to avoid it: [How to deal with nested callbacks and avoid “callback hell”](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deal-with-nested-callbacks-and-avoid-callback-hell-1bc8dc4a2012/)

as a note: your `request.post` callback should raise a syntax error as you are trying to use `await` inside of a synchronous function

```js
request.post(params, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    status = 0
  } else {
    status = 1

    const params = {
      secretArn: 'xxx',
      resourceArn: 'xxxx',
      sql: 'UPDATE pins SET status = \'DISABLED\' WHERE Pin_Code = \'XXX\' and status=\'ENABLED\'',
      database: 'pincodes'
    }
    
    const update = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise()
     //            ^
    // Compiler should refuse to run this
  }
})
```

Comment: @kilan exactly same issue but how i can resolve that

Comment: use either `async/await`, promise chaining or classic callbacks. I don't know the APIs dealing with so so i can't really help you much. try marking the function handed to `request.post` as async and as suggested move the `callback()` into that function after the `if-else`